# What exception to throw in Java?

Tags: java

Let's say I've got a map from Football team -> enum (e.g., `"Barcelona FC" -> FootballTeam.BARCELONA`). What exception should I throw if some team is not there?

I'm thinking about `RuntimeException` vs `IllegalArgumentException` but neither of them fits in here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html):

> Thrown by various accessor methods to indicate that the element being requested does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider using Java's [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) type in such situation. If your method returns something like `Optional<Team>` then you express that the team that client is requesting may not exist. And you leave the decision about what to do to the caller. For example:

- caller may use `Optional<Team>.ifPresent(Consumer<Team> consumer)` to continue processing only if specific team exists
- caller may use `Optional<Team>.orElse(Team team)` to return specific value (including `null`) if requested team does not exist
- caller may use `Optional<Team>.orElseThrow(Supplier<Throwable> supplier)` to produce a specific exception that has to be thrown when requested team does not exist.

I would say that throwing an exception should be your last option since it requires a proper handling to allow your program to continue processing.

Comment: When you get seduced by `Optional`, think of the way it clutters your API. At many places plain `null` would do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

While [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748784/2408342) is perfect, I'd like to mention that you can always create your own exception if you are not satisfied with the built-in Exception classes.

```
public class YourException extends Exception {

}
```

and `throw` it from anywhere

```
throw new YourException();
```